# Can't choose location in when creating an Azure SQL Database Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create an Azure SQL database Server on Azure for the first time. I'm trying to select a location for the server but I'm not getting any available values in the drop down list and any value I type says 'no results found'. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved itself shortly after. I had just upgraded my account to include a pay as you go plan and I guess it was either I had to wait a certain amount of time before the settings updates or I just had to refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be that the [Resource Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-services-resource-providers#registration) for SQL Database is not registered. Typically creating a resource through the Portal registers the provider, but your permission set may not allow this if you are not a subscription owner. That may also mean that you are not able to register the provider yourself either.

Comment: Solved itself shortly after. I had just upgraded my account to include a pay as you go plan and I guess it was either I had to wait a certain amount of time before the settings updates or I just had to refresh the browser. Thanks anyway.